# Sabre: Enhanced Air Book being called twice

Tags: sabre

I have noticed that when EnhancedAirBook method is called twice, separately for 2 Flight Segments.

In the Last/Second Response of EAB:
   TravelItinerary and AirPrice details gives me the combined result of both the Segments. So I was wonder why not consider only the last result and proceed with details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single call to EAB should be enough to book and get the total price of multiple segments at once.

If you make multiple calls to EAB with the same session, and with IgnoreAfter=false flag in PostProcessing, the segments you ask the service to book on each call will be concatenated into the same reservation, thus, you get the total price after the second call.

Comment: ThankQ for confirming me, yes as per my requirement I need to call twice, and indeed am calling PostProcessing with IgnoreAfter=false. So I can omit the first response and proceed with last one happily :)